# To delete question or to not delete question

Tags: discussion

I asked this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210026/lost-rep-from-edited-question-delete-not-showing-up Someone quickly answered this question in a comment. Should I delete the question in this kind of situation either on meta or main?

Comment: [This user makes a good point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210026/lost-rep-from-edited-question-delete-not-showing-up#comment673120_210026).

Comment: @Bart yeah but in general

Answer (score 4):

The general answer for "should I delete my own question" really boils down to "does it help the community to have it remain?"

Realize that the first part of this also implies some form of diligence at searching for possible dups prior to the question being asked.

The community and site grows upon good questions getting good answers.  Sometimes, even a... less than ideally worded question can help too in that it guides people who find it, as a duplicate, to the authoritative question.

Thus ask yourself:

- Is this going to get a good answer?
- Is this something that someone else would look for and should be directed to another question?

If either of those are 'yes', then leave it (possibly flagging it as a duplicate).  If the answer is 'no', then delete it.  Realize also that questions that are considered abandoned will be deleted by the system in their own due time - this, however is no excuse not to do housekeeping yourself.